# Angular - pass input value to css

Tags: css, angular

Is it possible in Angular to use a value passed into the component in the css

I have an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khqkmc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fblock.component.css).

It's a simple Angular component with css, when the window is resized a media query in the css changes the block color.

This media query is at fires at 600px.

Is it possibe to change this 600px using a value passed into the component

```
.block{
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 600px;
}

@media(min-width: 600px){
  .block{
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

Update

I'd like to create a component where I can control when the media query works when the component is created

so adding the component might be like this.

`<block media="500"></block>`

the media query in the css would then look like

`@media(min-with: 500px){}`

So the component is reusable but when the media query takes effect is determined when the component is added

Comment: What you try to do here. I can give you an example of an event triggered by the size change of the window.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do here. But I belive that could be more easy define several media querys for differents size.

Comment: I have updated the questions, hopefully explaining it better

Comment: You could just show or hide the component through the media query. I don't think coupling the component with it is a good idea.